# Embedded document in mongodb : 1-side relation on delete/update

Tags: php, mongodb, formbuilder

I've searched for a while if there was already a solution about it, but it seems there's not what I'm looking for.

I'm new to mongo and php and currently working on a project where we have many objects, here's a little sample about what's beeing done:

(A) I've created a document " Activity " each have :
- an ID, 
- a name,
- an intensity

All is working fine about this, (it looks like bellow in the php class file w/o the setter & getter)

```
/**
 * @MongoDB\Document
 * 
 */
class Activite
{
    /**
     * @MongoDB\Id
     */
    protected $id;
    /**
     * @MongoDB\Field(type="string")
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    protected $nom;

    /**
     * @MongoDB\Field(type="string")
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    protected $intensite;
```

}

(B) After that I've created another document " Category " where it also has :
- a name
- an embedded document of Activies

The relation is that a Category can have multiples Activities (OneToMany)

```
/**
 * @MongoDB\Document
 */
class Categorie
{ 
/** 
 * @MongoDB\Id 
 */ 
protected $id; 
/**
 * @MongoDB\Field(type="string")
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 */
protected $nom;

/**
 * @MongoDB\EmbedMany(targetDocument="Activite")
 */
protected $activites;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->activites = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}
```

}

I've successfully added my Category to the database with the formbuilder

```
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('nom',TextType::class, array(
            'attr' => array(
                'placeholder' => 'Nom pour la catégorie',
            )))
        ->add
        (
            'activites', DocumentType::class, array
            (
                // extract from :
                'class' => 'AppBundle:Activite',
                // use property Activite.nom as dropdown choice
                'choice_label' => 'nom',
                // data used as display for check boxes or radio or dropdown
                'multiple' => true,
                'expanded' => true
                // put as comment to get selectbox, dropdown, checkbox or radio
            )
        )
    ;
}
```

(C) my problem comes here, I'll try to explain it as clear as possible but it's weird.

(1) if I create 2 Activite, let's call them ActTest1 & ActTest2, they'll globaly exist in the database which is fine.

(2) if I create 2 Categorie, call them CatTest1 & CatTest2 without ticking any Activite to include them. these documents are created successfully and exist in the database with an empty array of Activite (normal)

(3) if I edit CatTest1 to have ActTest1 and ActTest2 and CatTest2 to have only ActTest1

the schema now looks like that (according to what I read in the Terminal) :

```
[list of Activities]
```

(I want them to be defined independantly to make embedded copies in each Categorie)]

```
{
ID : 1
Name : ActTest1
Intensity : soft
}
, 
{
ID : 2
Name : ActTest2
Intensity : Hard
}
```

and now :

```
[list of Categories]
```

(also made independant)

```
{
ID : 3
Name : CatTest1
Activities :
[
    {
    ID : 1
    Name : ActTest1
    Intensity : soft
    }, 
    {
    ID : 2
    Name : ActTest2
    Intensity : Hard
    } 
]
},
{
ID : 4
Name : CatTest2
Activities :
[
    {
    ID : 1
    Name : ActTest1
    Intensity : soft
    }
]
}
```

(4) Now if I edit CatTest1 and I untick ActTest2 to remove it from the array, ActTest2 which is supposed to exist only in CatTest1 as embedded document it ALSO delete the Activity ActTest2 from the list of Activities

now looks like that (according to what I read in the Terminal) :

```
[list of Activities]
```

(I want them to be defined independantly to make embedded copies in each Categorie)]

```
{
ID : 1
Name : ActTest1
Intensity : soft
}
```

and :

```
[list of Categories]
```

weird

```
{
ID : 3
Name : CatTest1
Activities :
[
    {
    ID : 1
    Name : ActTest1
    Intensity : soft
    }
]
},
{
ID : 4
Name : CatTest2
Activities :
[
    {
    ID : 1
    Name : ActTest1
    Intensity : soft
    }
]
}
```

I really don't get why it does that. Is it because in the formbuilder, when I fetch the data from the database to make the form, since it's the exact copy (ID aswell) when i delete the copy from the parent, it also delete the child which is the original thing ?

(5) My 2nd problem is about the update, we previously saw that the copy in the parent is bound to the child globaly defined so if a modification of the parent call a modification of the child I expected that a modification of the child would chain a modifications on parents that contain this child (or at least its copy)

if I keep the example we had after the deletion, if I edit ActTest1 to rename it as ActTest3 and change the intensity to Hard i get this result:

```
[list of Activities]
```

.

```
{
ID : 1
Name : ActTest3
Intensity : hard
}
```

and :

```
[list of Categories]
```

still weird

```
{
ID : 3
Name : CatTest1
Activities :
[
    {
    ID : 1
    Name : ActTest1
    Intensity : soft
    }
]
},
{
ID : 4
Name : CatTest2
Activities :
[
    {
    ID : 1
    Name : ActTest1
    Intensity : soft
    }
]
}
```

I could aswell delete that new ActTest3 that it wouldn't affect CatTest1 nor CatTest2

I'm open to any suggestion or explanation, there must be something I missed or didn't understand properly, but at the moment, I'm lost.